# Unauthorized error in User authentication in Bot in Government Cloud(GCC High)

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I am getting Unauthorized error, bot setup details are given below. I have tried the same setup in commercial azure and it's working. Issue is only in GCC High Azure.

bot Setup in Azure portal (portal.azure.us)

- Created Azure Bot in Azure portal.
- Add new client secret in Bot Azure App.
- Added redirect URI in authentication settings "https://tokengcch.botframework.azure.us/.auth/web/redirect"
- In Bot configuration in Azure portal

  - Configured Messaging endpoint
  - Created oAuth connection setting - Test Connection is working.

Used TeamsAuth [Sample code](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/46.teams-auth).

- Updated AppSettings.json file.

  - MicrosoftAppId
  - MicrosoftAppPassword
  - ConnectionName
- Added this code in startup.cs file as per [this Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=userassigned%2Caadv2%2Ccsharp#register-the-azure-ad-identity-provider-with-the-bot). (tried this and without this code also)
  `string uri = "https://apiGCCH.botframework.azure.us"; MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(uri); AuthClientConfig.OAuthEndpoint = uri;`

---

I have made changes as per the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/how-to-deploy-gov-cloud-high?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) and still getting error.

`Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadGateway' at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityWithHttpMessagesAsync`

- Using Bot Framework SDK version 4.16
- Startup.cs file has this line: `services.AddSingleton<BotFrameworkAuthentication, ConfigurationBotFrameworkAuthentication>();`
- Added configuration setting as per article as given below
  `{ "MicrosoftAppId": "db9c0376-41c2-4abc-bee6-a1c2f64b4f61", "MicrosoftAppPassword": "ad8...", "ConnectionName": "ccsGraphAuth", "ChannelService": "https://botframework.azure.us", "OAuthUrl": "https://tokengcch.botframework.azure.us/", "ToChannelFromBotLoginUrl": "https://login.microsoftonline.us/MicrosoftServices.onmicrosoft.us", "ToChannelFromBotOAuthScope": "https://api.botframework.us", "ToBotFromChannelTokenIssuer": "https://api.botframework.us", "ToBotFromChannelOpenIdMetadataUrl": "https://login.botframework.azure.us/v1/.well-known/openidconfiguration", "ToBotFromEmulatorOpenIdMetadataUrl": "https://login.microsoftonline.us/cab8a31a-1906-4287-a0d8-4eef66b95f6e/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration", "ValidateAuthority": true }`

---

I have tried the bot in Teams and Web chat Channels. getting below excetion in both

`Exception Message: Microsoft.Rest.HttpOperationException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized' at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.OAuthClient.GetSignInResourceWithHttpMessagesAsync(String state, String codeChallenge, String emulatorUrl, String finalRedirect, Dictionary2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.BotSignInExtensions.GetSignInResourceAsync(OAuthClient operations, String state, String codeChallenge, String emulatorUrl, String finalRedirect, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.UserTokenClientImpl.GetSignInResourceAsync(String connectionName, Activity activity, String finalRedirect, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.UserTokenAccess.GetSignInResourceAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, OAuthPromptSettings settings, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.OAuthPrompt.SendOAuthCardAsync(OAuthPromptSettings settings, ITurnContext turnContext, IMessageActivity prompt, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.OAuthPrompt.BeginDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(String dialogId, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  at Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.MainDialog.PromptStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\Bot\46.teams-auth\Dialogs\MainDialog.cs:line 51  at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.WaterfallDialog.OnStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.WaterfallDialog.RunStepAsync(DialogContext dc, Int32 index, DialogReason reason, Object result, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.WaterfallDialog.BeginDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(String dialogId, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)`

Comment: Could you please confirm if you are following this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/how-to-deploy-gov-cloud-high?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp document?  Since GCC High needs different configuration for authentication.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT, Thanks. I tried as per the article, still not working. I have update description, please check and let me know.

Comment: Thank you for confirming, we will check this and update you.

Comment: Could you please confirm if you are using CloudAdapter? Since the above sample doesn't use CloudAdapter, that could be a reason why the configurations aren't applied. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/how-to-deploy-gov-cloud-high?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#use-the-cloud-adapter

Comment: In the sample I have used [AdapterWithErrorHandler](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/46.teams-auth/AdapterWithErrorHandler.cs) class is already derived from CloudAdapter.
Can you give me a sample project code that works in GCC High.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT, Please let me know if you have any working sample that I can use for GCC High bot.

Comment: Currently we do not have any sample to share, and the team is looking into this issue, I will keep you posted on the updates.

Comment: The issue in GCCH has been fixed, can you please check and confirm once.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT, Thanks, now GCCH Bot authentication is working. However  adaptive card image control is not working in GCCH Bot, I will file separate thread for this. Thanks